# Calculate total working hours

Tags: php, mysql

Im using this to calc total hours of work:

```
$result = mysql_query("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ff AS SELECT vecka, namn, dagid, start, stop, vstart, vslut, arbtid, arbtim, UNIX_TIMESTAMP( stop )/3600 - UNIX_TIMESTAMP( start )/3600 AS value2 FROM schematabell;");
```

Now i want to calculate the time between the column "start" and the time "19:00" the same day, (if column "stop"is greater then "19:00"). I also want to calculate the time between "19:00" and "23:59" (if stop is greater then midnight).  How do you achieve this. The start and the stop column is in datetime format.

Comment: You should also check out http://dba.stackexchange.com ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the difference in SQL. The following statement should help. I currently cannot check if it works in real database.

```
TIMEDIFF(start,DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 19 HOUR))
```